# Is there any command line in Golang to check syntax error of my go source code & write the errors to a file?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func plus(a int, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
}
func plusPlus(a, b, c int) int {
    return a + b + c
}

func main() {
    res := plus(1, 2)
    fmt.Println("1+2 =", res)

    res = plusPlus(1, 2, 3)
    fmt.Println("1+2+3 =", res)
}
```

This is my Go Source code.
`gofmt -e my_file.go` is working But I am not able to write the errors to a text file.

Answer (score 2):

`gofmt` will output the errors to the standard error. You can simply redirect the standard error stream of `gofmt` to a file on unix systems like this:

```
gofmt -e my_file.go 2>a.txt
```

Checking it:

```
more a.txt
```

Output:

```
my_file.go:8:1: expected declaration, found '}'
```